# Inheritence over shared library boundaries

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, shared-libraries

I have two binaries, libA.so and exeB. libA exports many of it's functions, including a few classes. Consider the following simplified example:

From libA.so:

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

class EXPORT Foo
{
public:
    EXPORT Foo(); // implemented in cpp
    EXPORT virtual ~Foo(); // implemented in cpp

    EXPORT virtual int func(int b); // implemented in cpp
};

class EXPORT Bar : public virtual Foo
{
public:
    EXPORT Bar(); // implemented in cpp
    EXPORT virtual ~Bar(); //implemented in cpp

    EXPORT virtual char anotherFunc(char d); //implemented in cpp
};
```

Moving on to the executable B:

```
class Baz : public Bar
{
public:
    void useFuncAndAnotherFunc(); //implemented in cpp
};
```

In Baz.cpp:

```
Foo *p = /* ... */;
Bar *q = dynamic_cast<Bar *>( p ); // The culprit
```

During the compilation stage, I am greeted with the following error:

```
undefined reference to `typeinfo for Foo'
undefined reference to `typeinfo for Bar'
```

Even though I'm exporting the functionality of those classes, the compiler still complains. The virtual inheritence and virtual functions are required because another project, C, overrides them (unit testing). However, project C links against a static library version of this code and no errors are given. This seems to only apply to *.so variants.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The linker has no idea about functionality, it looks for symbols. You are not exporting all the symbols needed for a class to function. The linker tells you exactly which symbols are missing. You cannot fix this by adding attributes to the C++ sources, as there are symbols that has no direct correspondence in the source. You need to generate an export list by hand, or just export everything from your library by default.

Comment: With regards to understanding which symbols are missing, my compiler doesn't tell me what to specifically export. The only errors I get are the ones listed above. I will try exporting everything using the `-fvisibility` switch.

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce your error though I thought I knew exactly why and when it appears. I need some more experiments...

Comment: Oh, which version of g++ are you using?

Comment: GCC 4.6. I think I'll just add `-fvisibility` and get it over with. I have a hunch that the compiler is creating some functions, like copy constructor, which is not being marked visible. If you post your comment as a reply, I'll mark it closed.

Comment: I'm only getting this error if I *don't* mark the class with the visibility attribute. I'm also using GCC 4.6. Using `-fvisibility=default` is not recommended for any .so you would distribute, so I'd rather find another solution. Can you reproduce the problem in a small self-contained example? Say, does the code you have posted reproduce it? Which compilation/linker flags are you using?

Comment: So, we use -fvisibility=hidden by default and we were manually specifying classes to expose.